# Selenium with Cucumber - Jenkins | How to configure specific feature to run using TAGS in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cucumber

My runner file in my local system

[image]

My Jenkins configuration

[image]

Feature structure

[image]

As per my requirement, I have created separate features

```
{IndiaTransaction,CreateTransaction,BrazilTransaction,Mexico Transaction.features}
```

The above syntax will run all the features But I want to run specific features in my Jenkins, So how to configure it? I have tried below 2 methods it is not working, please help me to resolve

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **build step** with **Execute shell** in Jenkins for the project and use the command below:

`mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @CreateTransaction,@BrazilTransaction"`

And you can remove the **tags** option in cucumber runner class because the same thing you can do with `-Dcucumber.options="--tags @tagName"` in the command line

Please make sure you are using same tags in the feature files as well as in the command line.

Comment: Thanks for your comment I am parametrizing the tagname so can you help me to add the tag name in the script?

Comment: test -Dcucumber.options="--tags {Tagname}" -DJAWS_HOSTNAME=${Environment} can you confirm is this correct

Comment: What is *JAWS_HOSTNAME*? Is it an environment variable?